# JMX Connection to Mule 4 Project running Locally

Tags: mule, jmx, mule4

How do you connect a JMX agent to a Mule 4 project running locally? When I launch JConsole I see two mule-related processes called `org.mule.runtime.module.reboot.MuleContainerBootstrap` but I cannot connect to either.

I've tried running my project with the following flags and connecting remotely:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1096
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=localhost
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had no problems connecting to (localhost:1096) using just these properties:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1096
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

JConsole gave me a warning about the insecure connection (no SSL). I accepted to connect insecurely and that was enough.

However when adding `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=localhost` is keeps failing to connect. This looks like a Java issue.

If you only want to ensure local connections you can replace it with `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true` which should give you the expected result.

Having said that, this is all a pure Java JMX topic. Mule 4 doesn't expose any MBeans over JMX like Mule 3 did so there is no specific reason to connect with JMX.

I'm not sure why you are using jconsole given that VisualVM is a much modern and powerful alternative, unless you are just testing the local JMX connectivity ;-)

Comment: JConsole was just what I happened to have in my toolbox at the time :) I'll give it a shot with VisualVM & the parameters you provided. Thanks!

Comment: You may need to install an MBeans plugin inside VisualVM if you want to inspect beans. It even supports a JConsole plugins plugin I believe.